# Handling of dialogs generated by processes started through windows powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to automize the installation of a component on windows 7 by invoking it's setup.exe through cmd or porwershell. 
However, the installation process generates several deterministic dialogues, which have to be answered automatically as well.

How can I do that?

Comment: MSI version of the installer, command line Switches etc... What has you done so far? do you have any code snippet?

Comment: I specifically need to start the setup.exe, which opens a dialog asking me "Do you want to install the component". I need to handle that dialog automatically (as part of a script) and not manually.

Comment: Maybe you should use not powershell but some test instruments like `TestComplete` (https://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/free-trial)?